# controling bldc motor with atmega32

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

is it possible to control the speed of a bldc motor using a direct connection to ATMEGA32 microcontroller? Or there should be an interface since motors need more voltages than the microcontroller (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Ultimately this depends on the motor; there are those with low enough current to be run directly though generally speaking drivers are required.  If you had spent a few seconds to do a web search, you would have found more information than a single question here would.  Also note the many links in the sidebar to the right.

Comment: The ATmega32 can drive/sink about 20mA@5V on each port pin, with some more limitations. You can find such information in the datasheet, page 360ff. https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwikndeGnL3ZAhVNyqQKHbUUC_oQFgg-MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2FDeviceDoc%2FAtmel-8155-8-bit-Microcontroller-AVR-ATmega32A_Datasheet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3TwQLydk6TwMwo_77cYh3L That's not enough to drive motors directly.

Comment: @Janka - there are motors for which that is enough.  Spinning one extracted from a CD-ROM drive is a common demo, typically done open-loop as well.  Series resistors may be used to keep the current within bounds - obviously the torque is minimal, usually it's just the motor bell spinning, without anything like a CD or fan on it.

Comment: From those japanese 1:500 model trains maybe?

Comment: Ah, okay, no load condition. That could work.

Comment: To do any real motor power work , the device to get is a 3 phase module that interfaces with PWM, direction and software for acceleration , velocity profiles with feedback. or 1 to 16 bit resolution Stepper Motor modules for 2 phase motors with free software.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I did a research, but since my electronic knowledge is very little, I couldn't understand. I don't know who gave me a negative, but believe me that's unfair.

Comment: No, you either did not do a web search, or you did not actually read the results.   If you had, you would have found numerous applicable articles on both direct drive low current demos and FET based practical high current drivers.  If you had bothered to *read* those articles, you would not have asked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each GPIO of the Atmega328P can provide maximum 40mA @ 5V per I/O pin. If your DC motor has rated current and voltage within the Atmega328P range, then it's speed can be directly controlled from PWM pins on the arduino.

If the current rating of BLDC motor is higher(used in drones) then you need to use ESC(Electronic Speed Controllers) which can be controlled from arduino PWM.

Comment: Thanks, you said on the arduino though, did u mean the ATMEGA328P?

Comment: @Ali Padida The controller used in the arduino uno R3 is Atmega328P